# How to render frames precisely without waiting for the thread to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, low-latency

I have a java App and I am Loading 3 Gif files into BufferedImage Arrays and want to display them.

I have a simple Thread that is executed every e.g. 16ms (~ 60fps) using Thread.sleep()

In this method, I am calling the paintcomponent method to draw on the GUI component.
But I don't want the Thread (Runnable) to wait for the Method to end rendering because the Delay is more than 16ms afterward - even if it is not measurable.

Here's a snippet inside my Runnable JLabel (Currently the fast/efficient method)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (active) {
        repaint(); //Takes 0ms
        i++; // Counter used inside paintComponent()
        Thread.sleep(speed * multiplier));
        if (i + 1 == frames.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(frames[i], 0, 0, x, y, observerFrame);
    g.dispose();
}
```

I tested it and the repaint methods take 0ms. Probably not measurable.
But isn't it still unprecise? Or maybe inefficient?

So the (simple) math is done inside the Thread. But how do I ensure that the timing is precise? I mean it is still precise enough but it still depends on the speed of the pc

After the Answer of @Reto Höhener I did some research and tried another method.
But it is still inefficient and lags when rendering the images (BufferedImages btw):

This is one big attempt I did where I thought that it would be better:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(16, this);

Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 

//called by executor
@Override
public void run() {
    i++; // Counter used inside paintComponent()
    Thread.sleep(speed * multiplier));
    if (i + 1 == frames.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}

//called by timer & runs on EDT
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    executor.execute(this); //Costs no time and has enought time to complete
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(frames[i], 0, 0, x, y, observerFrame);
    g.dispose();
}
```

So this way I ensure that

1. The repaint is done in the EDT
2. The math is done by another Thread using executors

Even if I was proud after compiling and running it the results made me cry...

With the first method, the JVM uses ~10% of the CPU. Everything is fine and running on the fps for all 3 Frames.

The second try uses less CPU but is bad performing.
I don't know why but the GUI is responsive but the rendering is slow almost 3x slower.

**The goal** is to render images in 60 frames per second without lag.

**The point** here is that I tried an attempt where I thought that it is conceptually better but it did even worse.

So my question is if there is a better and more precise way to achieve this.
Otherwise, I will stay at the Simple Thread based solution.

regards
Nur1

Comment: Use `executor.submit()` to get `Future`s for all tasks, *then* call the `get()` method on each future. All tasks run in parallel. If you want no pause, pass a callback to the method so it can itself put the result somewhere visible and just execute it.

Comment: executor.submit() is the same as executor.execute() except that you are working with the futures and can iterate through and stuff. This would be heavier overall IMO. @Bohemian

Comment: Heavier? It’s about *parallelism*. There’s not much overhead in handing work to an ExecutorService - a few microseconds. But running everything concurrently shortens the total elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

First it would probably be helpful to learn just a little bit about the [Java Event Dispatching Thread (or AWT Event Queue)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) concept.

My suggestion would be to use one thread that is only responsible to call a *`.repaint()`*-method on your component. Instead of rolling your own thread, consider using *`javax.swing.Timer`* for this, it already uses a thread behind the scenes, and is able to coalesce multiple events if they arrive too quickly.

Then use another thread that is only responsible for calculating the information required to paint. One approach is to render into a buffer image. The *`.paint()`*- or *`.paintComponent()`*-method of your display component then only has to paint that image.